# Java why is implementing an interface necessary?

Tags: java, interface, implements

I've just started Java, and are going through examples online at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html

Then I got to implementing an interface, while I understand the concept behind it, but it seems weird to me, as in the interface declaration you only defines it, and in the class that implements this interface you'll still have to write it's functions. So why use it at all?

I tried the sample code, and then change the code to remove the interface, and they both work the same. So my question is when will implementing interface be used? It looks unnecessary to me. Thanks in advance!

Sample Code online:

```
public class RectanglePlus 
    implements Relatable {
    public int width = 0;
public int height = 0;
public Point origin;

// four constructors
public RectanglePlus() {
    origin = new Point(0, 0);
}
public RectanglePlus(Point p) {
    origin = p;
}
public RectanglePlus(int w, int h) {
    origin = new Point(0, 0);
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
public RectanglePlus(Point p, int w, int h) {
    origin = p;
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

// a method for moving the rectangle
public void move(int x, int y) {
    origin.x = x;
    origin.y = y;
}

// a method for computing
// the area of the rectangle
public int getArea() {
    return width * height;
}

// a method required to implement
// the Relatable interface
public int isLargerThan(Relatable other) {
    RectanglePlus otherRect 
        = (RectanglePlus)other;
    if (this.getArea() < otherRect.getArea())
        return -1;
    else if (this.getArea() > otherRect.getArea())
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;               
}
}
```

Code that I changed to, taken out the interface, it still works the same

```
public class RectanglePlus {
public int width = 0;
public int height = 0;
public Point origin;

// four constructors
public RectanglePlus() {
    origin = new Point(0, 0);
}
public RectanglePlus(Point p) {
    origin = p;
}
public RectanglePlus(int w, int h) {
    origin = new Point(0, 0);
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
public RectanglePlus(Point p, int w, int h) {
    origin = p;
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

// a method for moving the rectangle
public void move(int x, int y) {
    origin.x = x;
    origin.y = y;
}

// a method for computing
// the area of the rectangle
public int getArea() {
    return width * height;
}

// a method required to implement
// the Relatable interface
public int isLargerThan(RectanglePlus otherRect) {

    if (this.getArea() < otherRect.getArea())
        return -1;
    else if (this.getArea() > otherRect.getArea())
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;               
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{

    RectanglePlus newRect = new RectanglePlus(20, 30);
    RectanglePlus somerect = new RectanglePlus(50, 100);

    System.out.println("Area of newRect is " + newRect.getArea());

    System.out.println("Area of somerect is " + somerect.getArea());

    if((newRect.isLargerThan(somerect))==1)
    {
        System.out.println("newRect is bigger");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("somerect is bigger");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: But your modified `RectanglePlus` won't be usable where `Relatable` is expected...

Comment: I think the tutorial is not very clear as the isLargerThan can only compare object in same class. I did another class called SquarePlus, then try to compare the two by using if(newRect.isLargerThan(somesquare)==1). It won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. If you will have more than one implementation of the interface.  Say you have `Shape` and subtypes is `Rectangle`, `Oval`, etc.  If you want to write code that can do something with shapes in general, you need an interface which all of the subtypes implement - the interface is the set of methods you know that any `Shape` will have.
2. If you are writing an API - you are writing a library which someone else will use.  You provide other people with interfaces - this is the stuff that it's okay for them to call.  You will implement the interface, and the implementation class may have more methods - and you would like to be able to change those methods later, but your users should be able to pick up the new version of your library and use it with their old code.  By separating the interface from the implementation, you give the public something they can use, but preserve for yourself something you can change without hurting existing users.

Comment: Great, thanks! But when I try to define a new class named SquarePlus, and try to compare the two by using newRect.isLargerThan(somesquare), it won't work, it says SquarePlus cannot be cast to RectanglePlus. I guess I need to read more on how to use it

Comment: Any chance of an example by an chance? How to use the interface of isLargerThan if I want to compare between Square and Rectangle class. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, just include ``newRectIsLargerThan()`` in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is to facilitate type/interface reuse. You can pass a sub-type's object where a parent type object is expected. You can refer to http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html.

This basically allows you to deal in an abstract way. Your program can handle objects of different Classes as long as they implement certain behavior (or implement an interface or extend from a class)

Comment: That link example is for extend

Answer (score 0):

If you implements `Relatable` it allows you to find the largest object in a pair of objects, for any objects that are instantiated from a class that implements Relatable. Otherwise you only can find the largest object in a pair of objects that are instantiated from the same class.